# Datastore is putting a different ID value when importing from csv file

Tags: csv, import, datastore, bulkloader

I am importing data from csv file to datastore using appcfg.py

My problem is that the ID value inserted in datastore is different from the value in csv file.

I think the error is in the bulkloader.yaml, I don't know how to import the value.

This is my csv file:
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=xC9UVVty

This is my bulkloader.yaml:
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=W3t9c6qd

And this is the result in datastore:

```
ID/Name = id=1121   
casillaEspecial = N     
claveEntidad = aghzfmhheS1mb3IYCxIRRW50aWRhZEZlZGVyYXRpdmEiATEM
EntidadFederativa: name=1
.
.
.

ID/Name = id=1122   
casillaEspecial = N     
claveEntidad = aghzfmhheS1mb3IYCxIRRW50aWRhZEZlZGVyYXRpdmEiATEM
EntidadFederativa: name=1
.
.
.

ID/Name = id=1123   
casillaEspecial = N     
claveEntidad = aghzfmhheS1mb3IYCxIRRW50aWRhZEZlZGVyYXRpdmEiATEM
EntidadFederativa: name=1
.
.
.
```

As you can see, the ID's in csv file are: 1,2,3, whereas in datastore are 1121, 1122, 1123

I hope you could help me please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was any problem. I only changed the billing status of my application to Enable and all things started to go very well. After changing the status I tried to upload the csv file again and magically the ID didn't have more problems, the import was made correctly.